# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Logged in User, But Redirect doesn't work. How to solve these issues? Here is the

Login components code:

```
const Login = ({ props }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const alert = useAlert();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { isAuthenticated, error, loading } = useSelector(
      (state) => state.auth
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        props.history.push("/");
      }

      if (error) {
        alert.error(error);
        dispatch(clearErrors());
      }
    }, [dispatch, alert, error, loading, props, isAuthenticated]);

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(login(email, password));
    };  
    return ()
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

Comment: `({ props }) => {` ----> `( props ) => {`

Answer (score 2):

you destructure props from props? Maybe you meant `({ history, aProp, bProp })` ?